# Bash read loop does not stop after EOF

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to read a large text data file, line by line. Sample code:

```
lines=0
while IFS=$' \t\n'
do
    lines=$(($lines+1))
    read val
    echo "lines=$lines val=$val"
done < myfile
```

Problem: the loop reads past the end of the file !

```
$ wc -l myfile
41788 myfile
```

It goes fine at the beginning, I can see the data printed, but the loop does not stop after 41788. The counter goes on running with empty lines and I have to CTRL-C'it to stop.

Checked the data file, nothing special. size=5088370 bytes, the fields are tab separated (1).

```
$ file myfile 
myfile: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Any clue of what is going on here ? Did I miss something ?

(1) The fields are actually read with `read -a val`, but I tried the simplified code above to reduce my MCWE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're saying as long as IFS was set to `$' \t\n'` successfully, your loop will run.  It should be something like this instead:

```
while IFS=$' \t\n' read -r val
do
    ((lines++))
    echo "lines=$lines val=$val"
done < myfile
```

The default value of `IFS` should be `$' \t\n'` so setting it to that may be redundant.  I also believe that `read` by default will read whole lines, and I think even setting IFS to `$' '` will still cause it to read the whole line.

If you want `read` to delimit by spaces you can use the `-d` switch like this:

```
read -r -d' ' val
do
    ((lines++))
    echo "lines=$lines val=$val"
done < myfile
```

This will loop through every space delimited string in `myfile`.

Comment: Wow ! Was so simple... Thanks, had that in front of me, couldn't see it, as it **did** correctly read the lines! Bash is hard.

Comment: This is a typical SO syndrome: probably copy/pasted that snippet from somewhere without thinking about it.

Comment: yep, Bash's `read` has `-d` to set the "line" delimiter, standard `read` just reads (logical) lines, where I assume the "logical" part comes into play if you backslash-escape a newline.

Comment: Uhhhm, `: $((++lines))` or `: $((lines++))` or `lines=$((lines+1))` please.

Comment: `((lines++))` (without the `$`) would also work, and is perfectly idiomatic in bash.